# Finding an element by partial id with Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, regex, selenium

I am trying to locate an element with a dynamically generated id. The last part of the string is constant ("ReportViewer_fixedTable"), so I can use that to locate the element.  I have tried to use regex in XPath:

```
targetElement = driver.FindElement(
    By.XPath("//table[regx:match(@id, "ReportViewer_fixedTable")]"));
```

And locating by CssSelector:

```
targetElement = driver.FindElement(
    By.CssSelector("table[id$='ReportViewer_fixedTable']"));
```

Neither works.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That is because the css selector needs to be modified you were almost there...

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table[id*='ReportViewer_fixedTable']"))`
```

From https://saucelabs.com/blog/selenium-tips-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified:

```
css=a[id^='id_prefix_']
```

A link with an `id` that starts with the text `id_prefix_`.

```
css=a[id$='_id_sufix']
```

A link with an `id` that ends with the text `_id_sufix`.

```
css=a[id*='id_pattern']
```

A link with an `id` that contains the text `id_pattern`.

You were using a suffix which I'm assuming was not the partial link text identifier you were supposed to be using (unless I saw your html, which means try showing your html next time). `*=` is reliable in any situation though.

Comment: How do I apply this to do a partial match for CSS class names? I am trying to look for label elements which either have the class 'custom-label' or 'countable-custom-label'.

`By.CssSelector("label[class$=custom-label")` doesn't seem to work.

I can just use By.ClassName twice and combine the results but would still like to know how this can be achieved using CssSelector.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
targetElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[contains(@id, "ReportViewer_fixedTable")]"));
```

Note this will check for all the elements that have id which contains (and not only ends with 'ReportViewer_fixedTable'). I will try to find a regex option that would be more accurate answer to you question.

Comment: and yes a dirty way would be .//table[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 22) = 'ReportViewer_fixedTable']

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work irrespective of the XPath version. First, create a method somewhere in your COMMON helper class.

```
 public static string GetXpathStringForIdEndsWith(string endStringOfControlId)
    {
        return "//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id)- string-length(\"" + endStringOfControlId + "\") + 1 )=\"" + endStringOfControlId + "\"]";
    }
```

In my case, below is the control ID in different version of my product ::

v1.0 :: ContentPlaceHolderDefault_MasterPlaceholder_HomeLoggedOut_7_hylHomeLoginCreateUser

v2.0 :: ContentPlaceHolderDefault_MasterPlaceholder_HomeLoggedOut_8_hylHomeLoginCreateUser

Then, you can call the above method to find the control which has static end string.

```
By.XPath(Common.GetXpathStringForIdEndsWith("<End String of the Control Id>"))
```

For the control ID's which I mentioned for v1 & v2, I use like below :

```
By.XPath(Common.GetXpathStringForIdEndsWith("hylHomeLoginCreateUser"))
```

The overall logic is that, you can use the below XPath expression to find a control which ends with particular string:

```
//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id)- string-length("<EndString>") + 1 )="<EndString>"]
```