# Choose element by partial ID using Selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium, getelementbyid

I am trying to reach an web element in Selenium in Python 2.7. The element ID is like this:

```
cell.line.order(240686080).item(250444868).unitCost
```

The first number string '240686080' is known, but the second number '250444868' is unknown beforehand.

I tried to reach it by something like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("somewebsite.com")
driver.find_elements_by_id('input.line.order(240417939).item('+ '\d{9}'+').unitCost')
```

So my questions is, is there anyway we can search and reach this element only with part of the ID known?

I found  similar question answered below, but it was in C#. And unfortunately, I don't know C#.

[Finding an element by partial id with Selenium in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961178/finding-an-element-by-partial-id-with-selenium-in-c-sharp)

Thank you in advance!

**Edited 4/8**

The element is coded like this:

```
<td id="cell.line.order(240417939).item(250159165).unitCost" class="or_monetarydata">
    <input id="input.line.order(240417939).item(250159165).unitCost" type="hidden" value="135.00" 
    name="order(240417939).item(250159165).unitcost"></input>

    135.00

    </td>
```

I could get the element list by

```
value=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'input.line.order(240417939)')]")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although the answer is in C#, the underlying solution is still the same, by using CSS selectors:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[id*='cell.line.order(240686080)']')
```

or XPath will also be able to do this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, 'cell.line.order(240686080)')]')
```

Comment: I could use the 2nd method to get a list, and the last one is what I want to reach. But I could not use [-1].get_attribute('value') to get the value attribute. Do you know why? Thank you.
The source code of this item is like this:
<td id="cell.line.order(240417939).item(250159165).unitCost" class="or_monetarydata"><input id="input.line.order(240417939).item(250159165).unitCost" type="hidden" value="135.00" name="order(240417939).item(250159165).unitcost"></input>
      
135.00

    </td>

Comment: Forget it. I replaced 'cell.line.order(240686080)' with 'input.line.order(240686080)' get what I need. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Arran: Its giving me  
imgLink  = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('img[id$='Image_img']')
                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Tried replacing the outer ' with " I am unable to find the div. Any ideas?