# Finding An Element Based off a partial ID using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get some weather data off of a website using selenium. On the html file they look something like this:

```
<div id="tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud-20240225-0700" name="tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud-20240225-0700" class="container_value " .>
    <div class='box-offset'>10</div>
</div>
<div id="tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud-20240225-0654" name="tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud-20240225-0654" class="container_value " .>
    <div class='box-offset'>9</div>
</div>
<div id="tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud-20240225-0648" name="tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud-20240225-0648" class="container_value " .>
    <div class='box-offset'>7</div>
</div>
```

The first parts of the IDs are always the same, but the latter half changes based on the time/day.

I figured I could use `driver.find_elements(By.ID, "tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud")` but that doesn't seem to work. I also know of By.XPATH and PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, but I am not sure if they would work in my case.
I looked at the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845563/choose-element-by-partial-id-using-selenium-with-python)
and tried

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]")
```

and that gave me

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="007ad7b2-c5ba-46a8-8f5b-cbe0ea396b55", element="1c616c23-d457-4799-9c20-5a831d2895f1")>
```

I'm not sure if that's giving me what I want, and it's definitely not in a form that I can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a partial ID match with XPath.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("your_website_url_here")

# Find elements with IDs containing "tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud"
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]")

# Iterate through found elements
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)  # This will print the text inside each element
```

This XPath expression `//*[contains(@id, 'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]` will find all elements with IDs containing the string “`tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud`”. Then, you can iterate through these elements and extract the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the element it gave you without `headless`, then see if it is or not.
webdriver.click()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//[contains(@id,'tdatmo1FFrad6Noeud')])
print (element.text.strip())
```

Then, see if the output matches your desired outcome. If it doesn't, please give the link to that webpage and I'll try finding out a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments/suggestions

1. `find_element(By.ID, locator)` won't work because it's expecting the full ID, not a partial.
2. You can use a partial ID with a CSS selector

   ```
   div[id^='tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud']
   ```

   or an XPath, like you've already used... I would suggest you add `//div` instead of `//*` because that will better filter down to only the elements that you want.

   ```
   //div[contains(@id,'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]
   ```

   I prefer CSS selectors because they are better supported, more performant, and the syntax is simpler.
3. When you use `find_element()` (singular), if more than one element matches it just returns the first element. You may need to use `find_elements()` (plural) to return all matching elements.
4. Another option is to use the text inside the element, e.g. '10', '9', '7', to locate the desired element, e.g. for '10'

   ```
   //div[contains(@id,'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]/div[text()='10']
   ```
5. You can test your locators in the browser using the devtools console. To open the devtools, press F12. Use `$$()` to test CSS selectors, use `$x()` to test XPaths. For example, the below tests the XPath above

   ```
   $x("//div[contains(@id,'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]/div[text()='10']")
   ```

   If it returns only a single element, you're good. If it returns more than one, you'll need to make your locator more specific.
6. The seemingly random text you printed is likely from something like

   ```
   e = driver.find_element(locator)
   print(e)
   ```

   It's just printing the WebElement class info which is just GUIDs. You can use `print(e.text)` to see the text contained in the element (e.g. '10') or `print(e.get_attribute('outerHTML'))` to print the HTML of the element (e.g. `<div id="tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud-2024..."></div>`). You may find that helpful when debugging although I prefer to use the dev console instead because it's faster and gives me more info.

Answer (score 0):

The received object `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="007ad7b2-c5ba-46a8-8f5b-cbe0ea396b55", element="1c616c23-d457-4799-9c20-5a831d2895f1")>` is simply a `WebElement` from which you have several extension methods...

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]")
text = element.getText()
size = element.getSize()
```

... and much more. Find [a list of the options in the Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

Assuming you just want the text of the elements, there's another method with with an extension to Selenium:

```py
from browserist import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://example.com")
    texts = browser.get.texts("//*[contains(@id, 'tdatmo1-FFrad6Noeud')]")
    for text in texts:
        print(text)
    
    # If you later want to just work with the Selenium web driver instance,
    # you can continue like this:
    driver = browser.driver
```

In full disclosure, I'm the author of [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/). This package is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.