# Webdriver implicit wait for a dynamic ID

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver in Java and I need to wait for an element which has a dynamic ID to show up on the web page.

For example, I have the following statement for the implicit wait:
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("dynamicID")))

`dynamicID` is the prefix of the element's ID that I am waiting for, and normally it comes with a number after which I can't really predict.

There was some good answers here [Finding an element by partial id with Selenium in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961178/finding-an-element-by-partial-id-with-selenium-in-c-sharp).

I tried to change my code to be

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(^="dynamicID")))
```

and it is not working.

I tried to use the page factory:

```
@FindBy(id ^= "dynamicID")
private WebElement something;
```

and it is not working too.

So I have to questions:
1. how do I use ID partial match in my implicit wait statement?
2. if I am using the page factory, and assume the @FindBy is working, how do I use this element `something` in the implicit wait?

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(something))
```

does not work.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use By.xpath, and use the xpath `starts-with` function, like so:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'dynamicID')]")));
```

The * is a wild character representing any element type.  If you know the tag, you can replace it.  For example, if it's a div:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'dynamicID')]")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial match for the `id` but you have to use either an `xpath` or `css` selector.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("tag[id^='dynamicID']")))
```

Where `tag` is the element's tag.