# Selenium webdriver upload download files using relative path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jenkins

I would like to upload a file with selenium webdriver. I can do this in local machine using the absolute path of the file :  String filename = "C:\Windows\Temp\"+"templatePMT.html";. 
I'm using Eclipse and a maven project with a pom.xml and. I commit this project on SVN. I use Jenkins software to run the test of the Web app on IE8. Jenkins is deployed on Red Hat 5.0.   ---- The problem is this : ----  how can I upload a file using a relative path instead of the absolute path ? The file is in resource folder of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at file detectors. http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload

Comment: hey guys, it's ok I got the error ! It's is just a small one... Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to get absolute path of the file and upload the content

`String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/res/test.pdf;
driver.findElement(By.id("elementID")).sendKeys(filePath);`

Also you can use find the element using cssSelector as well. Then the code would be;
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='elementId']")).sendKeys(filePath);`

See more regex here : [Finding an element by partial id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11961927/1461060)

Ref:  [Relative path of a file to upload a file](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/142e8kye48/help-pls-relative-path-of-a-file-to-upload-a-file#20140214cddv6owkb2u42lgxtpeb6qgpbu)

Comment: Thanks - this got me close - using Python I needed to use `os.path.abspath()`. Leaving this comment here as a breadcrumb for other Python users.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the absolute path of the resource file:

```
URL resource = Main.class.getResource("/templatePMT.html");
String absolutePath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toString();
```

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much for answering... 
I tried your suggestions but it doesn't work. This is how I do at this moment localy and it works : 
String filename = "C:/test.txt";
File file = new File(System.getenv("java.io.tmpdir"), filename);
// click on the button to choice a file       getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("exportNegativeCreditAction_fichier")).sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
// Click on the button to upload file
getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("exportNegativeCreditAction_upload_boutonEnvoyer")).click();
Could you show me please how to do for this on a remote machine.