# Getting elements from a Javascript pop up window in Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to scrape results from an online database. However, once I have selected my results and go to export them a pop-up window appears. Normally I would just switch the frame to this window but it appears to be javascript generated. While there are elements on this pop up, the specific name keeps changing. So for instance there is a submitButton id tag. However, it is alway appended with a different ending. So for instance it will be  id="submitButton_15bb0b69431" but the next time it will be something completely different such as id="submitButton_15bb0c03e8e". My normal method of finding by ID or CSS or XPATH, therefore, does not work.

How can I handle this window to select the elements I need? Could I perhaps somehow get the page source for the popup?

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
for i in listofpa:
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(i).click()

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mainContentRight > div.pagination > ul > li:nth-child(13) > a').click()

except:
    pass
```

## This is the part I am stuck on

```
time.sleep(5)
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.find_element_by_id("tsMore").click()
try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#saveExportLink_6').click()
    window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
    html = driver.page_source()
    print html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xpath I think you can try `//*[contains(@id,'submitButton_')]` or `//*[starts-with(@id,'submitButton_')]` to locate the element.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wildcard in your css selector to get the modal dialog:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id^="submitButton"]')
```

This will find the first element that has an id starting with `submitButton`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to find by a partial match.  In XPath you can use regular expressions.  In CSS selectors you can match by prefix.

In Java this would be something like (from memory, not tested):

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[id^='submitButton']"))
```

More details at this SO question.  [Finding an element by partial id with Selenium in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961178/finding-an-element-by-partial-id-with-selenium-in-c-sharp)