# Finding all the elements by partial css class with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961178/finding-an-element-by-partial-id-with-selenium-in-c-sharp#), but it is not exactly what i need.

I am trying to automate [2048](http://2048game.com/) using `Selenium`. As you start to play, the `class` of elements changes. The Tiles which has the value have 3, or 4 different classes with below patterns:

```
tile tile-1024 tile-position-1-2 
tile tile-2 tile-position-4-1 tile-new
tile tile-8 tile-position-1-4 tile-merged
```

I am wondering how can i `find` all the elements which has this pattern in their class:

`tile tile-[TEIL SCORE] tile-position-[Any Number]-[Any Number]`

Here is my my `HTML`. Sorry for image, the chrome console does not allow me to copy it without expanding it:

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based _HTML_ along with your _code trials_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the elements as per the pattern you can use the following *cssSelector*:

```
.tile[class^='tile-'][class^='tile-position-']
```

Comment: i have 1 more question. if it loads several `WebElement` how can i get each of these elements?

Comment: I am not sure how `loads several WebElement` (as per your comment) is different from `find all the elements` (as per your question) of-coarse you need to use **findElements()** method and possibly _WebDriverWait_.

Answer (score 1):

Adding regex is not possible in CSS. ONLY Available options are *,$,^.
But you can search based on following, which is as per your criteria, but probably it will match almost all tiles:

`div[class^='tile-'][class^='tile-position]`

Instead you can be more specific by providing number  and row of tile which you are specifically looking for, for ex tile having number 4 in row 2:

`div[class^='tile-4'][class^='tile-position-2]`